# How to remove multiple, repeating & unnecessary punctuation from string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Considering strings like this:

```
"This is a string....!"
"This is another...!!"
"What is this..!?!?"
...
// There are LOTS of examples of weird/angry sentence-endings like the ones above.
```

I want to replace the unnecessary punctuation at the end to make it look like this:

```
"This is a string!"
"This is another!"
"What is this?"
```

What I basically do is:
 - split by space
 - check if last char in string contains a punctuation
 - start replacing with the patterns below

I have tried a very big ".Replace(string, string)" function, but it does not work - there has to be a simpler regex I guess.

Documentation:

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

As well as:

> Because this method returns the modified string, you can chain together successive calls to the Replace method to perform multiple replacements on the original string.

Anything is wrong here.

EDIT: ALL the proposed solutions work fine! Thank you very much!
This one was the best suited solution for my project:

```
Regex re = new Regex("[.?!]*(?=[.?!]$)");
string output = re.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: Use regex for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
[.?!]*(?=[.?!]$)
```

should do it for you. Like

```
Regex re = new Regex("[.?!]*(?=[.?!]$)");
Console.WriteLine(re.Replace("This is a string....!", ""));
```

This replaces all punctuations but the last with nothing.

`[.?!]*` matches any number of consecutive punctuation characters, and the `(?=[.?!]$)` is a positive lookahead making sure it leaves one at the end of the string.

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/4wXFLR).

Answer (score 3):

Your solution works almost fine ([demo](https://ideone.com/VamiZW)), the only issue is when the same sequence could be matched starting at different spots. For example, `..!?!?` from your last line is not part of the substitution list, so `..!?` and `!?` get replaced by two separate matches, producing `??` in the output.

It looks like your strategy is pretty straightforward: in a chain of multiple punctuation characters the last character wins. You can use regular expressions to do the replacement:

```
[!?.]*([!?.])
```

and replace it with `$1`, i.e. the capturing group that has the last character:

```
string s;
while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[!?.]*([!?.])", "$1");
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Lge6gJ)

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense, I will try it out on my examples!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it without regExps:

```
    string TrimPuncMarks(string str)
    {
        HashSet<char> punctMarks = new HashSet<char>() {'.', '!', '?'};

        int i = str.Length - 1;
        for (; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (!punctMarks.Contains(str[i]))
                break;
        }

        // the very last punct mark or null if there were no any punct marks in the end
        char? suffix = i < str.Length - 1 ? str[str.Length - 1] : (char?)null;

        return str.Substring(0, i+1) + suffix;
    }

    Debug.Assert("What is this?" == TrimPuncMarks("What is this..!?!?"));
    Debug.Assert("What is this" == TrimPuncMarks("What is this"));
    Debug.Assert("What is this." == TrimPuncMarks("What is this."));
```

Comment: What do you mean by `suffix??""`? Your code works, but the coalesce operator doesn't return in this case an empty string if `suffix` is `null`, but rather if `str.Substring(0, i + 1) + suffix` is `null`.

Comment: @NotADeveloper Yeah, `??""` was redundant. Thanks.